# Facebook like button not displaying properly

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like

My goal is to have dynamic Facebook like buttons using a php variable in the url. I figured I'd first just try inserting a static like button to test it out, but I'm encountering some issues. When I first loaded the page, after inserting the FB code, the like button displayed correctly. Though, every time after that it just displays a white box, the size of the like button content, which flickers, then disappears.

My situation may be unique as this *is* a wordpress site, but I don't use any of the wordpress features, such as the post loop, or any design layout features. I just use wordpress to publish posts, which get forwarded to my own database, and I display them with my own code.

Right after `<?php get_header(); ?>` in my index.php, I've put:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=293105884122762";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Then in a random place on the site I've put:

```
<fb:like href="mysite.com" send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
```

I know I need to add the XML namespace for IE, but I figured it wasn't necessary yet.

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd really appreciate them.

Comment: A question: Is the URL declaration of your variable 'js.src' correct? If you want to pass parameters with via GET, they are seperated from the normal adress with a question sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook code just runs inline, so if it isn't included at the bottom of the page, you have to call `FB.XFBML.parse()` to re-parse the page HTML looking for `<fb:/>` tags. Another option would be to either place this javascript at the bottom of the page, or better yet use a hook in your `functions.php` to include it in `wp_footer`.

```
<?php
// this function will output the facebook javascript code
function add_facebook_javascript(){ ?>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=293105884122762";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
<?php
}
// this will hook your function to the "wp_footer" action
add_action('wp_header', 'add_facebook_javascript');
?>
```

Comment: Both of these answers completely make sense, and I expected it to work, but still no luck. I'm gonna keep experimenting, but I'm open to any other possible suggestions.

Comment: @iRector - Facebook has made some changes, please try the above (it was missing the fb-root div) and if that doesn't work, you may need to insert it immediately after your body tag. Let me know and I can update as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the replay! I ended up getting it to work by putting the JDK above the `<?php get_header(); ?>`. That doesn't make much sense to me, as the header has the body tag in it, but I'm not complaining.

Answer (score 2):

include the below lines of code on the page where your like button is:

```
<script>
    if (typeof(FB) != 'undefined' && FB != null ) {
          FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
</script>
```

hope it helps. this had solved my very similar problem.

Comment: Both of these answers completely make sense, and I expected it to work, but still no luck. I'm gonna keep experimenting, but I'm open to any other possible suggestions.